# Tensorflow, Change placeholder and pass values

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do this:

I have 2D-tensor, matrix with shape=(None, 4), so N examples with 4 element, 
[x, y, a, b].

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 4))
```

In next step, I want to have matrix m x n with value b at coordinates (x, y)

Shape of Y is also given. e.g. shapeY = (5, 5)

Example:

Input:

```
X = np.array([[0, 0, 10, 10], 
              [1, 1, 20, 20], 
              [2, 2, 30, 30], 
              [3, 3, 40, 40], 
              [4, 4, 50, 50]])
```

Output:

```
Y = [[10, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 20, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 30, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 40, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 50]]
```

This example is with actual values, but I need this with placeholders as part of tensorflow graph, before I pass real values. Result must be like this.

Comment: considering the shape of Y is determined at runtime, because it depends on max x or y, is it even possible?

Comment: No, you also have given size of Y.

Comment: It can also work when the shape of `Y` is dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) for this.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 4))

Y = tf.scatter_nd(tf.cast(X[:, :2], tf.int32),
                  X[:, 3],
                  [tf.shape(X)[0], tf.shape(X)[0]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(Y, feed_dict={X: np.array([[0, 0, 10, 10],
              [1, 1, 20, 20],
              [2, 2, 30, 30],
              [3, 3, 40, 40],
              [4, 4, 50, 50]])}))
```

This prints

```
[[10.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. 20.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 30.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. 40.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. 50.]]
```

Comment: Is there chance that we set the initial value to other values instead of 0?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want both `X` and '`Y` to be dynamic. If so then this code should work.

I test it by adding one more row to `init` and adding a row and column to the line.

```
    sess.run(op,{  ph : np.zeros((7,7))})
```

Mainly the variable `ax` in this code is dynamic and it is achieved by these two lines

```
ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
op = tf.assign(ax, ph, validate_shape=False)
```

The idea for that is from this git [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5492). Both `ax` and `init` in the code are fed.

There is also a comment about some custom logic to update the `zeros` tensor. This could be a proper TensorFlow API call. Not sure which one can do that.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

init = np.array([[0, 0, 10, 10],
                  [1, 1, 20, 20],
                  [2, 2, 30, 30],
                  [3, 3, 40, 40],
                  [4, 4, 50, 50],
                  [5, 5, 60, 60],
                  [6, 6, 70, 70]])

X = tf.placeholder( tf.int32, shape=(None, 4))

with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    ax = tf.get_variable("ax", dtype=tf.int32, initializer=tf.zeros((5,5),tf.int32), validate_shape=False)

ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
op = tf.assign(ax, ph, validate_shape=False)


def cond(i , size):
    return tf.less(i,size)

def body(i, size):
    with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        #Just split each row, put the value
        #and stitch it back and update the row.
        ax = tf.get_variable("ax", dtype=tf.int32)
        oldrow = tf.gather(ax, i)

        begin = oldrow[: X[i, 0]]
        end = oldrow[X[i, 1]: ( size - 1 )]
        g = tf.gather(tf.gather(X, i), 3)
        newrow = tf.concat([begin, [g], end], axis=0)

        ax = tf.scatter_update(ax, i, newrow)


        with tf.control_dependencies([ax]):
            return ( i+1, size)


with tf.Session() as sess :

    _,i = tf.while_loop(cond,
                          body,
                          [0,tf.shape(X)[0]])

    with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        ax = tf.get_variable("ax",dtype=tf.int32)

        sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
        sess.run(op,{  ph : np.zeros((7,7))})
        print( sess.run( [tf.shape(ax),  ax,i] , {  X: init }  ))
```

So for the values in this code the output is this.

```
[array([7, 7]), array([
       [10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 20,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 30,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 40,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 50,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 60,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 70]]), 7]
```